# Javascript Closure For Loop Array Push Same Value

Tags: javascript, arrays, closures

I figured out that this is closure's play but still after reading through most of the posts and questions, I am still baffled as am unable to solve this.

Could you please help or point where I am doing wrong. I tried defining function outside also tried array.forEach to name a few.

I  am using momentjs in angular ctrl. Tried arr.push as well.

```
var vesting = [];
var postCDate = grant_date.add(1, 'y');
vesting.post = {vesting_date: postCDate.toDate()};
for(var i = 1; i<=noOfInstallments; i++){
        vesting[i] = {
           // mul = integer & k= 'd' or 'y' or 'm' as per above
           vesting_date: postCDate.add(i*mul,k).toDate()
        }
}
console.log(vesting);
```

cosnole.log gives me same result in every item that to0 last result in all of the items.

Please guide.

Comment: What did you declare `vesting` as?  An array or an object?

Comment: What is `postCDate`?  In your loop you may setting *every* element to the same object.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Added the vesting and postCDate in above code. Setting same element to same object?? If I console.log just before every loop iteration, it gives me correct ans.

Comment: The MomentJS APIs like `.add()` do not return a new date - they modify an existing object. You have to explicitly make a new date for each new object you're creating.

Comment: @Pointy: tried var dt = postCDate; vesting[i] = {vesting_date: dt.add(i*mul,k).toDate()}. Same result

Comment: @SiddharthSrivastva: That's not making a new date, that's just the same thing you are already doing.

Comment: That does not make a new date object; it's effectively exactly the same. Try setting `postCDate` to `moment(postCDate)` on each iteration.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: so new date will be var dt = new moment(); But then how do I equal it to postCDate value; Please guide

Comment: @Pointy: Many Thanks.  Got it. Its working.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Thanks for help :-)